# Does the final coat of a Danish Oil finish need to be wiped?

Tags: finishing, tung-oil

Does the final coat (in this case third) of Danish Oil have to be wiped?  Or is it *not* OK to just let dry and then lightly sand/buff?

I ask because I am using the dark walnut version of the Watco product, which was applied very thinly, and currently have the exact color match I want, but if I wipe it down it will remove some of the solids and thereby lighten up the finish.

I'd like to not have to keep reapplying.

Comment: If you don't wipe it, it tends not to cure properly. It stays tacky for a long time (indefinitely, for all practical purposes). Your best bet is to wipe it and reapply after this coat has had time to dry.

Comment: Same as all the other coats. With blended oil finishes you *must* remove all excess, no choice. BTW are you always sanding between coats? You shouldn't, unless you're de-nibbing, in which case you might only need to use the rough side of brown paper. BTW this is one prime reason a lot of finishers would steer people away from a combo product like this. Wiped away to nothing as directed there's a chance you'll actually never get to the colour you truly desire.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've use Danish Oil before and like it, but this is the first time I needed to match something else that was pre-existing...always a bit of a struggle, that.  I only very lightly sand ("scuff sanding") with higher grit between last and 2nd-to-last coats.

Comment: I sanded between my final coat and rubbed the final coat in with 400grit and wipe off most everything but it has been 4 days and the surface is still tacky to the touch should I wipe it off. Cheers Rangers Lead the Way

Comment: @mblatz01, it's actually perfectly acceptable form to start sentences with conjunctions (esp. *but*, *and* and *or*) or with prepositions. There are supposed rules to the contrary but they're actually *style guides*, not hard-and-fast Rules (as they may purport to be, and have been characterised as by others for far too long in modern English usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep wiping.  You might be able to keep your wiping rag in a jar with a lid.  Keep it wet with the oil, and twice a day, wipe the surface with it to add another thin layer.

The danger with not wiping is having a thicker puddle or streak on it.  This will turn into a stripe of gummy junk.

With most drying oils, UV light will hasten the drying.

Note:  Colour matching can be tricky.  You can get a perfect match in one light, say under the fluorescents in your shop, and find that the match is nowhere near close under sunlight or under halogen light.